# Contacts Exiting Journey at Decision Split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android

We have a journey that has an API Entry event, being feed contacts that reset their password on our website.  The journey is supposed to send an email and push notification to our end users depending on if they have a DeviceID, iOS, or Android application, and have opted in to communications.

We filter contacts in a decision split before the push notifications using data from our MobilePush Demographics and Subscriptions attribute group.  **Our issue is that contacts are exiting our journey at the decision split before the iOS or Android Push notifications.**

It's not a mobile app issue (as we've been able to make direct sends) and we are able to perform a single send journey with a push.  Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds likely there's some issue with the decision split. Could you share the details of how that decision split's configured. Are all contacts exiting? Are only some?

Comment: All contacts have been exiting at the decision split.  We opened a case with SF and there's an issue with some code in the backend.